# hi, i want to get a json data and sent another json array according to the recieved data in a json link

Tags: php, android, json

i am getting the response from the andriod part when it is posted as string request bt if i try to post as json array request in my android part i am not able to get the data in my php link. i am posting my php code below`require_once('Connection.php');

```
<?php require_once('Connection.php'); $json = array();
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){     $username =
$_REQUEST['email'];     $dummy = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO email
(email) VALUES ('$username')");     $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM users1 WHERE
email='$username'";     if ($result1=mysqli_query($link, $sql1)){
            $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);       $user = $row1['uid'];
                if($sql4 = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM wish_list WHERE user_id = '$user'")){          if (mysqli_num_rows($sql4) > 0){
                while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql4)){
                    $item_id = $row3['item_id'];
                    if($sql6 = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM item_display WHERE item_display_id ='$item_id'")){
                        if (mysqli_num_rows($sql6) > 0){
                            $row6 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql6);
                            $item_name = $row6['item_name'];
                            $item_image = $row6['item_image'];
                            $item_price = $row6['item_price'];
                            $item_details = $row6['item_description'];
                            $arr = array($item_name,$item_image,$item_price,$item_details);
                            $array = array("Item" => $arr[0], "Image" => $arr[1], "Price" => $arr[2], "Description" => $arr[3]);

                            array_push($json,$array);


                        }
                    }
                }           }
                        $json1 = json_encode($json,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);             echo $json1;        }   }    }else{     $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["response"] = "Not clicked order";    echo
json_encode($response);      }




?>
```

my android code is

```
public Fragment_Wishlist() {

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wishlist, container, false);

        final Context context = getActivity();

//        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)
view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view); //       
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true); // //        LinearLayoutManager
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context); //       
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager); //        final
Wishlist_adapter wishlist_adapter= new Wishlist_adapter(context,
wDetailsList); //        recyclerView.setAdapter(wishlist_adapter);

      String email=AppController.getString(context,"email");
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();
        Map<String, String> postParam= new HashMap<String, String>();
        postParam.put("email", email);
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_UserEmail_post, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "hii"+response.toString());
                hidePDialog();
                try {


                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        Details details = new Details();
                        details.setHome_item(jsonObject.getString("Item"));
                        details.setHome_itemPrice(jsonObject.getString("Price"));
                        details.setHome_itemImage(jsonObject.getString("image"));
                        details.setHome_itemCount(jsonObject.getString("count"));
                       // mDetailsList.add(details);


                    }
                   // homeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
                hidePDialog();

            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest,
tag_string_req);
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: What does it have to do with android? Most of us doesn't know php.

Comment: Need your android code to further debug.

Comment: ok I will edit my question and add android code

Comment: now i editted my question and added the android code @ Nicholas Tee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code can please try to do some edition like below

```
   `StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_UserEmail_post, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "login Response: " + response.toString());
            hidePDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Product");

                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){

                    JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Details details =new Details();
                    details.setWishlist_item(json.getString("Item"));
                    details.setWishlist_price(json.getString("Price"));
                    details.setWishlist_image(json.getString("Image"));
                    String mi=details.getWishlist_item();
                    System.out.println("item"+mi);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    })  {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Post params to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("tag", "login");
            String email=AppController.getString(context,"email");
            params.put("email", email);
            System.out.println("ema"+email);


            return params;
        }`
```